# Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have Ubuntu 16.04. When I do

```
sudo apt update
```

I get the following output:

```
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_InRelease
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_InRelease
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-proposed_InRelease
```

How do I fix this issue?

When I do ls `/var/lib/apt/lists` I get the output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/17059541/

When I do `gedit /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_InRelease` I get the output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/17059579/

When I do `gedit /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_InRelease` I get the output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/17059594/

When I do `gedit /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-proposed_InRelease` I get the output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/17059610/

How to correct this invalid 'date' entry?

Comment: Could you add the contents of those files listed in that error message (in `/var/lib/apt/lists/...`) to your question ?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the contents of those files

Comment: I meant just the _content_ of `/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_InRelease` and the other two files listed in your error message, not the list of files in the directory, sorry.

Comment: Is the date on your system correct?

Comment: The command date in terminal displays correct date and time

Comment: @JonasCz I have posted the contents of the above said three files

Comment: @rancho, If you still facing this issue, could you post the output of `date --iso-8601='seconds' ; grep -r "Date:" /var/lib/apt/lists/; ls --full-time /var/lib/apt/lists/`